# How to change my gallery to work with a click rather than hover?

Tags: css

I'm a bit green when it comes to CSS and coding in gernal. I'm trying to make a gallery and have got this far using code from elsewhere:

http://mccarronandco.com/newsite/test.html

It's nearly there, but I'm trying to stop the main picture resetting when a user clicks anywhere else on the page, so when the 'focus' leaves one of the thumbnails. Here's the CSS for the page:

```
.gallerycontainer{
position: relative;
float:left;
/*Add a height attribute and set to largest image's height to prevent overlaying*/
}

.thumbnail img{
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.thumbnail:focus{
    background-color: transparent;
    outline:none;
}

.thumbnail:focus img{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/

}

.thumbnail:focus span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    top: -520px;
    left: 30px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Regards,

Andy